# Android Gradle Plugin: runProguard in productFlavors?

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

I have an Android library project and an app, which uses that library project. In the app's build.gradle file I have ProGuard obfuscate the whole app including the library project code:

```
//from the app project
buildTypes{
    release {
        runProguard true
        proguardFile 'proguard-project.txt'
    }
    debug{
        runProguard false
    }
}
```

All works well, the lib project and the app project both get obfuscated just fine.
However, I want to build my lib project "*standalone*", so I can distribute it without the app project. This of course means obfuscating the lib project on its own.

I cannot do this by using the `buildTypes` code in the lib-projects `build.gradle` and simply running proGuard, since this would break the app-project build, because then building the app would compile its code agains already-obfuscated lib-project code... :-)

What I need is a possibility to run ProGuard **only** if I build the lib-project in "standalone" mode, e.g. by passing a parameter, or executing a special task.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is your library a module inside your project? You can create a build.gradle for your library-module whit its own proguard config file. The name of your library public methods can't be obfuscated.

Comment: "This of course means obfuscating the lib project on its own" -- what makes you say that? The vast majority of Android library projects distributed as AARs are not obfuscated.

Comment: @CommonsWare: of course I can only speak for myself, and I'd (or: my employer) rather not have our code readably through decompilation.

Comment: @MartinCR: what exactly do you mean by _module_? It is a classic Android Library project, which can exist independent from the app project, if that's your question.

Comment: @paul-latzelsperger with Android Studio each module (each project inside your app) has its own build.gradle file, where you can define if it will be obfuscated or not. I think that you should create a specific proguard file for your library and obfuscate everything except the name of the public methods.

Comment: If you obfuscate your library how users of it will compile their projects? If you solve this I think obfuscating library will not be issue for your project compilation as well

Comment: I am aware of that, but I want to obfuscate the Lib-project depending on whether it will be used inside my app or if its built for standalone mode.
@EugenMartynov: of course the public API is excluded from obfuscation. However, the need to obfuscate is not up for debate :)
<br/>might different configurations be the way to go?

Comment: In this case i don't understand why lib obfuscation breaks your compilation? Public api is not obfuscated, nonpublic api you can not access

Comment: because my app uses not only the public API

Answer (score 0):

solved it myself. In the lib-project's build file I have two buildtypes and I publish them both:

```
publishNonDefault true
```

and the build types:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        runProguard false
    }

    release {
        runProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'

    }

}
```

this causes the `debug` and `release` APK to be created. In my app project's build file I then add an explicit dependency to the `debug configuration` by stating the dependency as follows:

```
dependencies{
    compile project(path: ':FancyLibProject', configuration: 'debug')
    //...
}
```

Of course in the app-project I also have two build types debug and release, which in turn invoke ProGuard in the same way as for the lib-project.
**Note:** I omitted the signing configs for the release build - without those the APK will **cannot be installed!**